# Replacing a semicolon with a space

Tags: r

Im trying to run text analysis on a list of keywords, but they are listed like a;b 2;c, so when I use tm to remove punctuation it becomes ab 2c, and i assume this breaks my frequently used terms analysis some how.

Is there a way to replace semicolons with spaces?

tm_map(Keywordcorpus,removePunctuation)

*EDIT I tried using gsub but the result became a value, and not in the same list as my other data! what went wrong?

Comment: you can use `gsub` on your text. `gsub(';', " ", keywords)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I tried it now, and used semicorpus<-gsub.... but the result became a value, so it was separate from my other data in the list, why did this happen?

Comment: You didn't give a reproducible example so we can't tell for sure. But most likely you didn't actually replace the original thing and instead just created something new.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data with the dput function

Comment: the data is literally just rows and rows of a;b;c a;Bc;d.  i wrote: > corpus<-gsub(';', " ",corpus) so it should replace itself. still became a large character value!

Comment: Share a reproducible sample of your data, `dput(droplevels(head(your_data)))` usually works well for that, so we can tell what data structure you're using. Indeed, `gsub` gives a character vector result, but we don't know what you're working with. You say "list" in your question, but `list` class seems unlikely... Please also mention any relevant packages you're using that aren't loaded by default. (`tm`? `tidytext`? Others?)

Answer (score 1):

I would guess you are messing up your assignements

See if this works for you

```
vector_of_characters <- c("a;b;c",
                       "a;Bc;d")

gsub(';', " ",vector_of_characters)
```

## Data

```
df_character_row <- data.frame(vector_of_characters)
```

## What won't work

This fails at finding the correct column

```
gsub(';', " ",df_character_row)
```

This fails at returning the value to the column

```
just_a_vector_of_characters <- gsub(';', " ",df_character_row$vector_of_characters)
```

## Right answer

```
df_character_row$vector_of_characters <- gsub(';',
                                              " ",
                                              df_character_row$vector_of_characters)
```

## That is maybe good enough reason to use the tidyverse or you should read assignments

```
library(tidyverse)
tb_character_row <- tibble(vector_of_characters)

tb_character_row

tb_character_row %>% 
  mutate(new_vector_of_characters = vector_of_characters %>%
           str_replace_all(';',' '))
```

## If for some god forsaken reason you find yourself with more than 1000 character columns

```
imagine_big_tibble <- tibble(a= vector_of_characters,b = vector_of_characters)
```

Maybe don't

```
imagine_big_tibble %>%
  pivot_longer(names_to = "old_column",
               values_to = "characters_in_there",
               cols = everything())
```

But if you really need to

```
imagine_big_tibble %>%
  map(str_replace_all, ";", " ")
```

Or

```
imagine_big_tibble %>%
  mutate_all( ~ str_replace_all(., pattern = ";", replacement = " "))
```

Comment: vector_of_characters <- c("a;b;c",
                       "a;Bc;d")

gsub(';', " ",vector_of_characters) this worked, but it still becomes a value. am i supposed to gsub my dataset file, my vector or my corpus? also when i inspect the value it just gives me a long list of numbers. so my vector is a List of 2665, but the new value becomes chr [1:5] "" "2665" "0".... really weird

Comment: @Gnubbish I edited my answer if it solves your question please consider upvoting and accepting it, you really should read more about R, I recommend https://r4ds.had.co.nz/